# Nuxt Front end with Larvalel api Nginx configuration

Tags: php, laravel, ubuntu, nginx, nuxt.js

I have a Nuxt application with a Laravel API on the same server and I am running into a situation where nginx is duplicating the /api with /api/api since I am using laravel api.php.

Here is my setup.  I have just a simple conf under sites-available on a semilink to sites-enable.

```
server {
        listen 80;
        root /var/www/html/nuxt-apt-front/dist;

        # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name example.com;

         location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
         }

        location /api{
          alias "/var/www/html/laravel-api/public";
          try_files $uri $uri/ @api;
          location ~ \.php$ {
                fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                include fastcgi_params;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /var/www/html/laravel-api/public/index.php;
        }
     }

       location @api {
          rewrite /api/(.*)$ /api/index.php?/$1 last;
       }

        include /etc/nginx/sites-available/*.conf;
}
```

Any ideas what I could be doing wrong?

ideally I would like to route to /api for laravel

```
http://example.com/api/login/google
```

right now if I had this below it seems to work.

```
http://example.com/api/api/login/google
```

Example of api.php

// Login through google sign-in.

```
Route::get('login/google', [GoogleAuthController::class, 'redirect']);
Route::get('login/google/callback', [GoogleAuthController::class, 'callback']);
```

Comment: Can you show your api route file?

Comment: @Aless55 sure, I updated my question with an example of the route.

Comment: The default laravel config is to prefix the api routes with api. AFAIK you can change this in your `RouteServiceProvider`

Comment: @apokryfos Exactly this is the problem. The author can either change their nginx config file or the method in their RouteServiceProvider. Is it really necessary to use the nginx config for your case?

Comment: @apokryfos know a way to handle it in nginx config?  rather handle it there if possible

Comment: @Aless55 thoughts?

Comment: If you want to go the Nginx way you will have to delete the prefix in the mapApiRoutes method in your RouteServiceProvider @chewie | if you are on laravel8 i think the method doesn't exist. Simply change the prefixed code in the boot() method.

Comment: How about  `rewrite /api/(.*)$ /api/index.php?/api/$1 last;` ? would that work? (Honestly I don't know)

Comment: @apokryfos look at my answer, this should be the easiest solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented above if you want to keep the Nginx File as it is, change the following code in your `RouteServiceProvider`:

```
 Route::prefix('api')
                ->middleware('api')
                ->namespace($this->namespace)
                ->group(base_path('routes/api.php'));
```

to this:

```
 Route::middleware('api')
                ->namespace($this->namespace)
                ->group(base_path('routes/api.php'));
```

It is somewhat self explaining, the prefix is added to each api route/call. By removing it, it is simply left out and there is only the one appended by your Nginx Config.